# What's the difference between Waste Water Reclamation and Waste Water Reuse?

Tags: water, terminology

I received a project which there's the follow topic:

**Waste Water Reclamation and Reuse**

Are they not the same meaning, reuse and [reclamation](http://www.ecologydictionary.org/wastewater_reclamation) in this case?

Comment: What have you found so far? You should know that we are **not** here to write your project for you.

Comment: @santiago you are so funny. I don't want anyone to write "my project", by the way it's not my project it's a project that I received to do the assessment, and I just wanted know the opinion of more specialists because to me reclamation and reuse have the same meaning. Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Water reclamation is the process of capturing, transporting and treating water so it can be be reused, particularly if the water is contaminated. Depending on the type of contamination treatment facilities can be a processing plant or a specially constructed/adapted system of biological wetlands with a slow flow of water through them.

Re-using water is using water more than once regardless of whether it has been treated or not. For waste water to be reused it must first be reclaimed and treated.

Comment: Thank you so much @Fred, now the topic makes sense to me. Regards.